# Absorb precipitates when heating water in a microwave?

Tags: boiling, water

I boil filtered water. I notice much precipitates in the water after heating it up in microwave. I would like to remove them, and I am thinking the ways do it.

Ways

- some absorbing stone etc ...
- some specific rough ceramic bowl to which those precipitates attach to (I  think this is the best bet)
- material of the bowl?

---

How can you remove precipitates in water after its heating in microwave?

Which material would you use for the bowl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply filter them out. A coffee filter should take care of even the finest minerals.

I doubt that you can effectively do it while boiling. Even if you give them sites to attach to, a lot will stay afloat.

Comment: Great idea! I think I need to buy one Mocca Master because I do not have yet one - for good coffee! I am just interested in how hot the water becomes in Mocca Master. It is not boiling there. So it may be problematic. Hmm - I must think further which coffee machine to buy. Do you have any recommendations for safe water boiling?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, precipitates fall to the bottom of the container.

Therefore, the standard procedure is simply to decant the liquid -- pour the liquid off the top, without pouring out the last little bit which contains the solids.